# Launch Application Virtualization Client app from C#

Tags: c#, process, launch, appv

I'm writing an application to serve as a launcher for many different apps, some of which are launched using the Microsoft Application Virtualization Client. What is the proper way to start these apps from C#?

I know I can use this:

`Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcessStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\path\to\app.lnk";
myProcess.Start();`

However, not everyone will have their app.lnk shortcut in the same place. Is there any way to use C# to launch the virtualization client and pass it \launch parameters?

Comment: you can use Application Data folder to store all your shortcuts, its will be a common place for any user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, here's the code:

```
Process myProcess= new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sfttray.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/launch \"name_of_appv5_app\"";
myProcess.Start();
```

Mainly just a matter of string formatting and escape sequences!